# UIKit Dynamics - Issue with referencing the UIDynamicAnimator from ChildViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, microsoft-dynamics

I have one UIViewController *container* with contains multiple UIViewController *boxes*. I'd like to apply physics behaviour to the boxes using UIKit Dynamics. The container defines the outer border.

[image]

The **UIDynamicAnimator** is an object in the container and all Dynamics behaviours are part of the boxes.

Problem: I run into error messages when I reference the animator from the boxes (childviewcontrollers) for adding the box behaviours.

Here's the error message

```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'View item (<UIView: 0x9972720;
> frame = (0 568; 120 40); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H;
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x9976f80>; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x9972780>>) should be a descendant of reference view in
> <UIDynamicAnimator: 0x9906d40> Stopped (0.000000s) in <UIView:
> 0x9916bf0> {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}'
```

**UIViewController Container**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDynamicAnimator* animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    _animator = animator;
...
}
```

Adding Boxes as Subviews and ChildViewControllers

```
- (void)tapOnContainer:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)touch {
...
            BoxViewController *note = [[BoxViewController alloc]init];
            [box setContainerObject:self];
            [self addChildViewController:box];
            [self.view addSubview:box.view];
}
```

**UIViewController Box**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _containerViewController = (ViewController*) self.parentViewController;
    _gravityBehaviour = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[self.view]];
    [_containerViewController.animator addBehavior:_gravityBehaviour];
...
}
```

Any idea how to get this working? Is it okay to split the UIDynamicAnimator and the UIDynamicBehavior objects like this?

Comment: By looking at your code, although it is not evident here, but I suppose your ultimate intention is to have different gravitational pull on each box, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, kind of. I'd like the boxes to be draggable. Therefore I need to add/remove UIGravityBehavior, UIPushBehavior, UIAttachmentBehavior to each box. This will be triggered by individual UIPanGestureRecognizers.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`_gravityBehaviour = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc]initWithItems:@[self.view]];`

Add your *small view* instead of `self.view`.